# How to create numbered list from tuples array?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I have the following list:

```
   let myList: [(String, Int, Double)] = [("A", 1, 1.5), ("B", 2, 2.5), ("C", 3, 3.5)]
```

And I am trying to produce the following output

```
1) A | 1
2) B | 2
3) C | 3
```

If I delete the 2nd element I want the output to be updated as well, like this

```
1) A | 1
2) C | 3
```

I'm new to Swift, so this is a lot to wrap my head around but how would I start something like this? This is my function, but I am not sure if this is the right way to start. And I'm wondering how I can get the extra symbols and keep the numbers in order. ( this value is going to be passed to a UILabel, so I have to keep all the elements together in one variable `result`)

```
func displayString(myList: [(title: String, id: Int, value: Double)]) -> String {

   var result = ""

   for i in 0..<myList.count {
     
    
    
   }

 

   return result 
 }
```

Comment: So all you have done before posting a question is writing an empty loop? I think you should at least try to solve the problem before you come here with your question, trying is a way better way to learn something compared to getting a ready solution handed to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the `1)` and `2)` as well on every line, have a look at looping through arrays using `enumerated` where you have access to the index as well as the item

It would look something like this:

```
func displayString(myList: [(title: String,
                                   id: Int,
                                   value: Double)]) -> String
{
    var result = ""
    
    // The first iteration, index is 0 and item is ("A", 1, 1.5)
    // Second time, index is 1 and item is ("B", 2, 2.5) etc
    for (index, item) in myList.enumerated()
    {
        // Since index starts from 0, you add +1 to start from 1 in the output
        result += "\(index+1)) \(item.title) | \(item.id)\n"
    }
    
    return result
}
```

The output would be:

```
1) A | 1
2) B | 2
3) C | 3
```

However, I urge you to explore higher order functions like `filter, map, reduce` etc which will shorten the code you write to do these things.

For example, you could get a similar result with something like:

```
func displayStringSwifty(myList: [(title: String,
                                   id: Int,
                                   value: Double)]) -> String
{
    return myList.reduce("") { val, item in val + "\(item.0) | \(item.1)\n" }
}
```

The output would be

```
A | 1
B | 2
C | 3
```

**Update**

A more succinct version provided by Leo Dabus in the comments:

```
myList.map { "\($0.title) | \($0.id)" }.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: Or simply `myList.map { "\($0.title) | \($0.id)" }.joined(separator: "\n")`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus - definitely more concise.

Answer (score 0):

```
let myList: [(String, Int, Double)] = [
             ("A", 1, 1.5),
             ("B", 2, 2.5),
             ("C", 3, 3.5)]

myList.enumerated().forEach { (index, element) in
    print( "\(index+1)) \(element.0) | \(element.1)" )
}
```

gives you

```
1) A | 1
2) B | 2
3) C | 3
```